# Pandas - calculate values based on computed LAG value without using a loop

Tags: python, pandas

**Input dataset:**

| Group | Height | Value | Rolling |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 0 | 2 | 100 |
| A | 10 | 5 | n/a |
| A | 20 | 3 | n/a |
| B | 0 | 1 | 98 |
| B | 10 | 4 | n/a |
| B | 20 | 2 | n/a |

**Goal:** Subtract the `Value` from `LAG(Rolling)` where `Height != 0` (per group), without using a loop if possible.

**Output Dataset:**

| Group | Height | Value | Rolling |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 0 | 2 | 100 |
| A | 10 | 5 | 95 |
| A | 20 | 3 | 92 |
| B | 0 | 1 | 98 |
| B | 10 | 4 | 94 |
| B | 20 | 2 | 92 |

Comment: Does `n/a` are NaN values?

Answer (score 2):

The idea here is to fill null values of `Rolling` column by the opposite  `Value` then group by `Group` column and apply cumulative sum:

```
df['Rolling'] = df['Rolling'].fillna(-df['Value']).groupby(df['Group']).cumsum()
print(df)

# Output
  Group  Height  Value  Rolling
0     A       0      2    100.0
1     A      10      5     95.0
2     A      20      3     92.0
3     B       0      1     98.0
4     B      10      4     94.0
5     B      20      2     92.0
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind overwriting `Value` column in the first entry of each group (with `0.0`), then this is straightforward.  Otherwise, make a copy of the `Value` column and use that.

```
sio = StringIO("""\
Group Height Value Rolling
A 0 2 100
A 10 5 n/a
A 20 3 n/a
B 0 1 98
B 10 4 n/a
B 20 2 n/a
""")

df = pd.read_csv(sio, sep='\s+')

df.loc[df.groupby('Group').head(1).index, 'Value'] = 0
df['Rolling'] = df.groupby('Group')['Rolling'].ffill() - df.groupby('Group')['Value'].cumsum()

print(df)
```

```
  Group  Height  Value  Rolling
0     A       0      0    100.0
1     A      10      5     95.0
2     A      20      3     92.0
3     B       0      0     98.0
4     B      10      4     94.0
5     B      20      2     92.0
```